# Send whole column to the function and check row by row

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

I want send whole columns to my function! Something like function `min()` or `max()`, is it possible?
How to check query results row by row? I wrote something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gowno.kiki(temppp INTEGER ) RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
DECLARE
val INTEGER := 0;
i tyczka%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT adres FROM tyczka)
    LOOP
        RETURN CAST(i.adres AS INTEGER);
        IF CAST(i.adres AS INTEGER) > val THEN
            val = CAST(i.adres_ AS INTEGER);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN val;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

For example, I have something like the following table. And I want to calculate the differences between the field in column `poziom_wody` where id is the same.

[image]

Comment: Please show sample data and your desired result.  You can't send a whole row to a function that takes one column, so I (for one) don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: What is wrong with `SELECT MAX(CAST(adres AS INTEGER)) FROM tyczka`

Comment: for example i have something like that http://www.pl.image-share.com/upload/330/79.jpg. And i want to calculate the differences between the fild in column "poziom_wody" where id is the same.

Comment: "And i want to calculate the differences between the fild in column poziom wody where id is the same." I"m sorry, could you put it more precisely what do you want to calculate?

Comment: SELECT poziom_wody FROM table WHERE id_rzeki = 1; we hawe two rows in first we have 155 and the second 140, the difference is 15. I want to make function to calculate this. Function param is ID and ruturn the difference, for id ID what I gave. But I don know how to taking row by row inside the function

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your function would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(temppp int)
  RETURNS INTEGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
   val int := 0;
   i   tyczka;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN
      SELECT * FROM tyczka
   LOOP
      RETURN i.adres::int;
      IF i.adres::int > val THEN
         val := i.adres::int;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN val;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Depending on your table definition this could be further simplified.

Depending on what you want to achieve exactly, there is probably a superior set-based approach. Looping is typically a measure of last resort in a relational database.

There *are* occasions where it's the best one, but people coming from procedural languages tend to over-use loops.

#### Added example

To get the difference between the maximum and minimum `poziom_wody` with the same `id_rzeki`:

```
SELECT max(poziom_wody) - min(poziom_wody) AS diff
FROM   tbl
WHERE  id_rzeki = 2;
```

This works for any number of rows.